# Proving $({1\over \sec^2a-\cos^2a}+{1\over \csc^2a-\sin^2a})\sin^2a\cos^2a={1-\cos^2a\sin^2a\over2+\sin^2a\cos^2a}$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with this trigonometry question:

> Prove that  $${\left({1\over \sec^2a - \cos^2a}+{1\over \csc^2a - \sin^2a}\right)\sin^2a\cos^2a={1 -\cos^2a\sin^2a\over2 + \sin^2a\cos^2a}}$$

I first tried coverting all identities  into sin and cos which gives
$${\left({\cos^2a\over 1 - \cos^4a}+{\sin^2a\over 1 - \sin^4a}\right)\sin^2a\cos^2a}$$

$${\left({\cos^2a\over (1 + \cos^2a)\sin^2a}+{\sin^2a\over (1 + \sin^2a)\cos^2a}\right)\sin^2a\cos^2a}$$
I don’t know what to do after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the next step naturally seems to be to put everything over a common denominator; e.g., $$\left(\frac{\cos^2 a}{(1 + \cos^2 a)\sin^2 a} + \frac{\sin^2 a}{(1 + \sin^2 a) \cos^2 a}\right) \sin^2 a \cos^2 a = \frac{\cos^4 a (1 + \sin^2 a) + \sin^4 a (1 + \cos^2 a)}{(1 + \cos^2 a)(1 + \sin^2 a)}.$$  Then the numerator simplifies to

$$\cos^4 a + \sin^4 a + \cos^2 a \sin^2 a (\cos^2 a + \sin^2 a) = \cos^4 a + \sin^4 a + \cos^2 a \sin^2 a.$$  This would *almost* factor into $(\cos^2 a + \sin^2 a)^2 = 1$, were it not for the fact that the coefficient in front of $\cos^2 a \sin^2 a$ is $1$ rather than $2$.  So we just add in the extra amount and subtract it:
$$\begin{align}
\cos^4 a + \sin^4 a + \cos^2 a \sin^2 a 
&= (\cos^4 a + 2\cos^2 a \sin^2 a + \sin^4 a) - \cos^2 a \sin^2 a \\
&= (\cos^2 a + \sin^2 a)^2 - \cos^2 a \sin^2 a \\
&= 1 - \cos^2 a \sin^2 a.
\end{align}$$

This takes care of the numerator.  The denominator simply requires expansion:

$$(1 + \cos^2 a)(1 + \sin^2 a) = 1 + \cos^2 a + \sin^2 a + \cos^2 a \sin^2 a = 2 + \cos^2 a \sin^2 a.$$

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

@heropup gave a detailed proof of the result.

On my side, I thought that using multiple angle formulae could be a way to go
$$\frac{1}{\sec ^2(a)-\cos ^2(a)}+\frac{1}{\csc ^2(a)-\sin ^2(a)}=-\frac{8 \left(\tan ^2(a)+\csc ^2(a)\right)}{\cos (4 a)-17}$$ Multiply by $\sin ^2(a) \cos ^2(a)$ and the lhs becomes
$$-\frac{24}{\cos (4 a)-17}-1$$ which also the rhs after similar manipulations.